# mouseEntered will not execute

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouselistener

I am trying to do a mouseEntered test to change a square colour however the MouseListener mouseEntered would not execute. The mouse is responding but only to clicks, pressed and release. So i am not sure what is going on. I hope you can help me point my problem thanks.

```
//Class
class RectangleClass extends JPanel{
    private int height;
    private int width;
    private boolean MouseEntered= false;
    private boolean MouseExit= false;
    private JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
//Inner class with mouse Event
    class RectangleAdapter extends MouseAdapter{

        public void MouseEntered(MouseEvent e){
            System.out.println("MouseEntered"); 
            MouseEntered = true;
            repaint();
        }

        public void MouseExited(MouseEvent e){
            System.out.println("MouseExited");  
            MouseExit = true;
            repaint();
        }

    }
//constructor
    public RectangleClass(int height,int width){

        myPanel = this;
        this.height=height;
        this.width=width;
        this.addMouseListener(new RectangleAdapter());
    }
//paint graphic
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        g.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, width, height);
        g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);

        if (MouseEntered){
            g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
            MouseEntered= false;
        }
        if (MouseExit){
            g.setColor(Color.orange);
            MouseExit= false;
        }
        g.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    }
}

public class RectangleContainer extends JFrame{

    public RectangleContainer(){
        setLayout(null);
        JPanel myPanel = new RectangleClass(100,100);
        myPanel.setBounds(50, 50, 200, 200);
        setSize(200,200);
        add(myPanel);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new RectangleContainer();
    }
}
```

Comment: `public void paint(Graphics g){`  Don't override `paint(..)` in a `JPanel` - it should be `paintComponent(Graphics)`.  And use `@Override` notation to check the method exists.

Comment: That is interesting, I haven't seen anyone do it that way. Would mind putting a sample code for me?

Comment: Try adapting it, and ask another question if need be.

Comment: I understand why you use paintComponent thanks Andrew.

Comment: wait actually i am lost with paintComponent lol. but i can understand it saying that i should use it to change the property of the drawn shaped and after that i pretty tried to used it and failed lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have started the `mouseEntered` method in your code with a capital M. Change it to lowercase m.

Comment: I thought the other answer was better (1st & more complete).

Answer (score 3):

You're not actually overriding the [mouseEntered](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html#mouseEntered%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29) method of `MouseAdapter`, you need

```
@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
```

Adding `@Override` will let the compiler check that you are overriding the correct method. The same applies for [mouseExited](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html#mouseExited%28java.awt.event.MouseEvent%29) BTW.

---

*Side Notes:*

- Don't use [`null` layout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html) - Always use a [layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)
- For custom painting override `paintComponent` rather than `paint`
- Java naming conventions indicate that all variables start with a *lowercase* letter which would make the variable `MouseEntered` `mouseEntered`

Comment: oh that was auto generated but eclipse i'll removed it now. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that Eclipse auto-generated any of the code that @Reimeus commented on.  1) Eclipse would write the correct method signature (probably with `@Override` notation.  Having done that, the method names would have correct case. 2) Eclipse would not automatically set the layout to `null` -- So what exactly are you blaming on the IDE?

Comment: The layout null part was my doing, i wanted to freely set the panel by x and y position. The mouseEvent part i am not sure how did that i must of copied and pase the boolean name in by mistake.

Comment: *"The layout null part was my doing, i wanted to freely set the panel by x and y position."*  Using `null` layouts will prevent you from progressing from trivial GUIs to ones that contain many components, have components added dynamically, are resizable, can use different PLAFs etc.  Learn how to use layouts combined with the spacing we can define in the layout constructors, and Swing based `Border` objects to give the GUI a reliable size and shape.

Comment: I am not very good with GUI but i will look into that and learn about it thanks for the tip