# How to add a mouseListener to a graphics2D rectangle

Tags: java, mouselistener

I would like to make a mouseListener that would trigger every time the mouse hovers over a rectangle (or some coordinates on the window). I thought about using mouseEntered but that only triggers when you move your mouse on the screen, not a rectangle etc (Heres what I tried

```
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    int mx = e.getX();
    int my = e.getY();

    if(mx >= 1000 / 2 && mx <= 1000 / 2 + 380) {
        if(my >= 300 && my <= 390) {
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    }

}
```

) but of course, that didn't work.
I know that there's probably a question like this, but I couldn't find it and I couldn't find anything that fit my question exactly.

EDIT: I realized that mousEntered was wrong and its actually mouseMoved! Heres the code:

```
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    int mx = e.getX();
    int my = e.getY();

    if(mx >= 1000 / 2 && mx <= 1000 / 2 + 380) {
        if(my >= 300 && my <= 390) {
            System.out.println("test");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html

And this:

[mouseEntered will not execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15457160/mouseentered-will-not-execute)

You should find some helpful notes and answers! Also, try printing out "mx" and "my" to the console to make sure that you have the right coordinates.

Comment: Didn't really help, I just want the mouseEntered method to triggers when the mouse enters a rectangle instead of the window.